# Set of Solutions of A Quadratic Equation with Coefficients in $\{0,1,\cdots , \ p-1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, finite-fields, roots

I was just playing with quadratic equations and this interesting question came into my mind. Say I have a set of quadratic polynomials $S=\{f_{(b,c)}(x)=x^2+bx+c:b,c\in \{0,1,\cdots, p-1 \}\}$ where $p\in \mathbb{N},\ p\ge 1$. I want to investigate how do the roots of the equations $f_{(b,c)}(x)=0$ vary over the complex plane as $b,c$ are varied. I found all the roots for the equations $f_{(b,c)}=0$ for the case $p=2$, i.e. when $b,c\in\{0,1\}$. I found the roots as $-1,\pm i,\omega,\omega^2,0,0,0$. So $3$ roots are at the origin and the rest of $5$ are on the unit circle $|z|=1$. I found this structure very intriguing. So, is there any general result on this?

Comment: "Unit Circle"? What unit circle?

Comment: I mean to say $|z|=1$ circle on the complex plane.

Comment: How do you mix here  the complex numbers field with the prime field of characteristic $\;p>0\;$ ??

Comment: I am taking the coefficients $b,c$ from the prime field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and looking at the roots in the complex field $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I'm not saying this couldn't make some sense somehow, but... *how*?

Comment: We have no sense in which we can multiply an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with one from $\mathbb{C}$. I guess you're really interested in the roots of polynomials with coefficients between $0$ and $p-1$ for primes $p$?

Comment: Yes, I am wrong in using the term "field", it should be the set $\{0,1,\cdots , p-1\}$

Comment: Not to mention that, for example, for $\;p=2\;,\;\;b=c=1\;$ , we get the irreducible quadratic $\;x^2+x+1\in\Bbb F_2[x]\;$ ...

Comment: Oh, I see @SamratMukhopadhyay. Then please edit your question.

Comment: But *anyway*: in $\;\{0,1\}\;$, for $\;b=c=1\;$ we get the quadratic $\;x^2+x+1\;$ , whose roots are $$\frac{-1\pm 3i}2$$Why do you say these roots are in the origin ?

Comment: For $b=c=0$, we have two roots at $0$ and for $b=1,c=0$ again we have one root at $0$. I was pointing at that.

Comment: Yes, but for $\;b=c=1\;$ you do **not** get that!

Comment: @DonAntonio, I think I could not convey the question properly. I know that for $b=c=1$ the roots are $\omega, \omega^2$ and that  is why I said that the "rest of the $5$ roots are on the unit circle." These five roots include $\omega,\omega^2,-1,\pm i$. So, essentially I am talking about all the roots of all the equations $f_{(b,c)}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two cases:

1. **The roots are real**
   The vertex of the parabola is at coordinates
   $$V\left( -\frac b2, c-\frac{b^2}4 \right)$$
   The roots can not be greater than $0$, since the coefficients of the polynomial are not negative. Moreover, the parabola has always the same shape, since the coefficint of $x^2$ is $1$. The modulus of the roots will be maximum when the vertex is most below and most left (sorry for my English), that is, when $b=p-1$ and $c=0$. This gives the root $1-p$.
2. **The roots are not real**
   Now, the real part is $-b/2$ and the imaginary part is
   $$\pm\frac{\sqrt{4c-b^2}}2$$

Regardless of sign, the modulus is
$$\frac{b^2}4+\frac{4c-b^2}4=c$$
so, again, the moduls of the roots is at most $p-1$.

Summing up, the roots of the polynomials are always on the disc of radius $p-1$. By the way, note that I have made no use for the fact that $p$ is prime, or even integer.